# Include HTML in Jekyll front matter (post title)

Tags: jekyll

How can I place HTML tags in a Jekyll post’s (YAML-encoded) front matter and stop this HTML from being escaped in the final output? My content, including titles of posts, uses multiple languages in addition to the main page language and this requires proper markup with `span lang="XX"` tags for screen readers and certain automated extraction. However, attempting to write the following:

```yaml
---
layout: post
title: A post that says <span lang="fr">Bonjour</span> and <span lang="es">Hola</span>
---
```

results in HTML output where these tags have been escaped:

```html
<h1 class="post-title p-name" itemprop="name headline">A post that says &lt;span lang=&quot;fr&quot;&gt;Bonjour&lt;/span&gt; and &lt;span lang=&quot;es&quot;&gt;Hola&lt;/span&gt;</h1>
```

I am using Jekyll minima theme.

Comment: What is you version of Jekyll? I can't reproduce my side, I do get the right html out of the front matter. Maybe also show us how you display your title (so the liquid part)?

Comment: The most recent version of Jekyll installable from gem, 4.1.0. I literally just installed yesterday according to the official Jekyll quickstart, and then imported all posts from my old Wordpress blog according to the same docs. The post titles on the Wordpress blog liberally used span tags, because WP allows that. Jekyll however escapes them as described. I have not made any changes to any of the theming etc. This is a totally default install with the minima theme.

Comment: I see that I do not encounter this problem once I install certain other themes and switch to them. Perhaps I should then report this as a bug either in the Minima theme, or in Jekyll’s official quickstart for former Wordpress users.

Comment: I would guess that, if this acts like that there was a filter set per design.

Comment: Try to open the file __layout/post.html_. and look for the title display, there should be your culprit

Comment: Yep, see: https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_layouts/post.html#L7 there is an `escape` filter used. Drop it and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, on the [minima theme](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) of Jekyll, that you are using, there is an [`escape`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/escape/) filter that is applied per design on the `page.title`.

From the documentation:

> Escapes a string by replacing characters with escape sequences (so that the string can be used in a URL, for example). It doesn’t change strings that don’t have anything to escape.

<sup>*Source: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/escape/*</sup>

If you want your `span` to display, you should edit the file *_layouts/post.html*  and remove this `espace` filter.

Your line 7 of this file should look like

```html
    <h1 class="post-title p-name" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
```

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/49f6dce0727a2441f0b0c265b41b5efc7b042eb6/_layouts/post.html#L7*</sup>

Change it so it reads

```html
    <h1 class="post-title p-name" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title }}</h1>
```

And you will have your expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. It should also be mentioned that a similar escape filter is present in the theme's layout file home.html and it is must be removed to show post titles on the index page properly.

Comment: The usage of the minima theme was the pointer in here. Glad that I could help. You could consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).